# how print asp.net MVC with Stimulsoft.Report.Web

Tags: printing, stimulsoft

how Print with Stimulsoft.Report.Web in asp.net MVC
''' StiReportResponse.PrintAsHtml(S); '''
not suport iny page

Answer (score 0):

The Stimulsoft report engine works on the server-side. The printer should be installed on the server.

Comment: I add .dll  Stimulsoft in Server